# How do I externalize the application.yml of config server (not the clients)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I would like to externalize and dynamically reload the configuration (application.yml) of spring cloud config server.

The idea is to avoid repackaging config server, when ever a new service comes in to use spring cloud config server.

Here is what i have tried so far -

1. Started Spring cloud config server with

   ```
   -Dspring.config.location=<path to externalized application.yml>
   ```
2. Enabled Actuator (that already comes with cloud server lib)
3. Update the application.yml adding a new repo
4. POST /actuator/refresh

The /actuator/env shows the updated configuration with the repo details added for the new service, however the response from config server the new config client config does not have the configuration of client config

When i restart the config server, it picks up the updated configuration

How can I get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you need to "repackage" the server for every new client? Surely you deploy the server once, pulling from a repo (or equivalent) of config per client/service, and point each client at the one server. The server shouldn't need to be touched, or even restarted, if a new client comes along. Alternatively embed the server in every client and have each client able to pull its own externalised config.